# System calls for handling touch in Android

Tags: android

Can anyone guide me about the system calls handling touch at the kernel level of an android phone.
We have searched for various system calls in touchscreen driver module but couldnt find any ..
Please suggest for samsung galaxy s 2

Comment: Why would you want to use the system call? Use native libs if you want, but I don't see any good reason to do this at the kernel level on Android